# Autopopulate combobox based on other combobox in access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, textbox, auto-populate

I have a problem with two comboboxes in access. I have one where you can select the postal code and another where you can select the city. Every city is connected with a postal code. In the dropdown menu of the comboboxes is only one column visible (so in postal code you can only see the postal codes but not the cities that correspond to the postal code). Due to the fact that there is only one column visible I think it's impossible to use the

afterupdate Me.combopostalcode=Me.comboboxcity.column(...)

I tried with the DLookup function but it doesn't work. It only works if I create one combobox (for instance a combobox postal code) and a textbox city. If I change the city textbox in a combobox and write a DLookup in both comboboxes to fill in each other with the right value no value for postal code is filled in the combobox postal code if I select something in the combobox city. It also doesn't work in the opposite way if I select a postal code and want the city filled in the combobox.

I read something about cascading comboboxes but I think it's not the right solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a query for second combox `Row Source` and in criteria field refer the first combobox. The use `ComboBox2.Requery` method to `afterupdate` event of first combobox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Harun24HR! I have some little questions about the answer. So in the afterupdate event of the first combox (postal code) I need to write this code: Forms!namequery!comboboxpostalcode.RowSource = "postalcode"                 
Where namequery= name of the query with the values postal code and city and where comboboxpostalcode = name of the combobox where you select postal code? And where do I need to write Combobox2.requery (comboboxcity.requery in this case)?

Comment: Can a postal code have multiple cities?

Comment: If you want two-way cascading comboboxes, not sure it is practical. I have seen it discussed but can't find any threads. If it can be accomplished, would definitely require VBA.

Comment: BTW, hidden (zero width) combobox/listbox columns can definitely be referenced.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking the same about two-way cascading comboboxes. I already did a lot of research to find the answer but didn't found anything. I can write very limited things in VBA if that's needed. I really appreciated your help!